# Confirming action before processing!

Tags: php, codeigniter, confirm

Am doing a contact management site in codeigniter, i have a function which delete the contact based on id.

For example the page will have all contacts listed. And each contact will have a link saying delete near it. The link will be to the function passing the id, like:

```
www.site.com/index.php/action/delete/23
```

So i want a confirmation box to ask user, yes or no for each link. So if user press yes it will be deleted and otherwise nothing happens. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I don't understand the question, and I don't think I am alone.

Comment: We will not write the code for you, only correct the bad code you've already written. HINT: You should be using AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a javascipt prompt:

**Your JS**

```
function confirm_delete(){
    var r=confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (r==true){
      //Do somthing
    }else{
      //cancel
    }
}
```

Then add an onclick event to your link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirm_delete();">Delete</a>
```

If you want something shiny and less intrusive may i suggest jquery with one of a multiple of confirm dialog plugins.

http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/

http://kailashnadh.name/code/jqdialog/

Answer (score 1):

You could have a confirmation page with a form to post back to the same url.  In the controller check whether the form has been submitted.  If it has, delete the contact. If not, display the confirmation page.

```
function delete($id)
{
    if ($this->input->post('confirm'))
    {
        $this->contact_model->delete($id);
    }
    else
    {
        $contact = $this->contact_model->get_contact($id);
        $this->load->view('delete_confirm', array('contact' => $contact));
    }
}
```

If you don't like the idea of an extra page you could use some javascript to display a confirmation box and do an AJAX post if the user confirms.

**Edit :**

Just as an aside, what I'd avoid doing is implementing the delete through a HTTP GET. A spider or bot following the delete links could inadvertently delete all the contacts.  Its better to use HTTP POST.